# VBA MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 with Yahoo finance

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new with VBA, and the issue is that I am trying to scrape the web: https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/Aluminum and get all sectors of each ticker of the list. The complex part (at least for me) is remove the filters "price" and "exchange" and send the request, I am using the following code, but I can´t not connect it propertly. Some suggestion? Many thanks

```
sub connect_to_web

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim url As String
Dim query as string

url="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/screener?lang=en-US&region=US&formatted=true&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com"

XMLPage.Open "Post", url, False
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

XMLPage.send ""

Debug.Print XMLPage.Status

XMLPage.send ""

Debug.Print XMLPage.Status

end sub
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the responsetext is       : responseText : "{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Bad Request","description":"Null Request"}}}" : String

Comment: What makes you confident that the problem is the code, not the URL you are using?

Comment: because if I inspect the headers sended by the navigator (using the post method) when I click in "Find stocks", the request URL is exact what I use in the code. I suspect the mistake is that I am not using a specific query or a correct header.